# HTMLPurifier: Allow embed

Tags: php, html, filtering, htmlpurifier

That is my allowed tags:

```
public function filter($str) {

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8');
    $config->set('HTML.SafeEmbed', true);
    $config->set('HTML.SafeObject', true);
    $config->set('Output.FlashCompat', true);
    $config->set('HTML.FlashAllowFullScreen', true);
    $config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'object[classid|width|height|data],param[name|value],embed[src|type|allowscriptaccess|allowfullscreen|width|height|wmode]');


    $PHTML = new HTMLPurifier($config);

    return $PHTML->purify($str);
 }
```

That is embed code:

```
<object classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' width='450' height='24'><param name='movie' value='http://rockdizfile.com.com/player/player.swf'><param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'><param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'><param name='wmode' value='transparent'><param name='flashvars' value='file=http://www4a.rockdizfile.com:80/d/wolc22zkfp4r2ge4elcuugteixfmw7h2yrxy2bvxyc73psaqhhbd2hix/8noptiencs83.mp3&duration=193.4'><embed src='http://rockdizfile.com/player/player.swf' width='420' height='24' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' flashvars='file=http://www4a.rockdizfile.com:80/d/wolc22zkfp4r2ge4elcuugteixfmw7h2yrxy2bvxyc73psaqhhbd2hix/8noptiencs83.mp3&duration=193.4' /></object>
```

But why filter function return this?

```
<object width="450" height="24" data="http://rockdizfile.com.com/player/player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="internal" /><param name="movie" value="http://rockdizfile.com.com/player/player.swf" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="flashvars" value="file=http://www4a.rockdizfile.com:80/d/wolc22zkfp4r2ge4elcuugteixfmw7h2yrxy2bvxyc73psaqhhbd2hix/8noptiencs83.mp3&amp;duration=193.4" /
```

Have and two warnings:

> Warning: Attribute 'classid' in element 'object' not supported
>
> Warning: Attribute 'allowfullscreen' in element 'embed' not supported